Error with Google map API
I have an aurra component with an embed VF in IFRAME.
The VF is displaying map using the google map API, I have some fonctionality in it, and it is working very well.
When I try to access to the current location I get the bellow error:
Check if Location Services are Enabled: Make sure that location services are enabled on your device.[Violation] Permissions policy violation: Geolocation access has been blocked because of a permissions policy applied to the current document. See https://goo.gl/EuHzyv for more details.

My additional code:
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            var currentLocation = {
                lat: position.coords.latitude,
                lng: position.coords.longitude
            };
        })

